# Implementing AOS into wordpress makes the targeted elements blank instead of fade-in

Tags: javascript, wordpress, animate-on-scroll

I am trying to implement Michalsnik's Animate On Scroll plugin into my wordpress website. But when I make the following div with "data-aos", as instructed, the element turns out blank instead of fading in.

```
<div class="textbox center branch-bg" data-aos="fade" data-aos-duration="600">
Immergez-vous
</div>
```

This is how I attempted the installation:

1) I added

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

to my header file to load the CSS and the Javascript.

2) I added the
    AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
function to my script in order to activate it (but disable it on mobile)

Here is a link to the webpage with an anchor. The first article is blank, though it should fade in on scroll.

http://latelierdegaia.ch/#content

Is there a step in the installation I missed? Am I doing something else wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after 3 hours of meddling around with code, I found the solution!

My mistake was, I was adding

```
<script>
AOS.init();
</script>
```

in the header, between the

```
<head></head>
```

tags, and actually I should add it at the beginning of the body, between the

```
<body> </body>
```

tags.

All the rest I was doing right.
Hurray!

Comment: Haha I just did the same thing, was about to post on here how to get it to work and realized I forgot the same thing!

Comment: Happy to know it could help!